# How to parse anchor javascript void (PHP) with simple.html.dom

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i want to parse from this exact line of code `<a class="Icon IconDownload" href="javascript: void(0);" isfilelink="true" data-key="K7YyNbVScsvMSS3WNzAzNzEyMjWyiLc0NjY1NrfEFIk3MjA0jzcwjDfSK0hJU7IGAA=="` **THE VALUE** `K7YyNbVScsvMSS3WNzAzNzEyMjWyiLc0NjY1NrfEFIk3MjA0jzcwjDfSK0hJU7IGAA==` and i don't know what to do.. Can anyone help me ?

This is what i have done so far:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

$anchors = $html->find('.IconDownload[data-key]');

foreach ($anchors as $anchor){
   echo $anchor->plaintext;
}
```

If i run this i get blank white screen.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine and i get the results that i want

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

$myArr = [];
foreach ($html->find('table a') as $anchor){

   $myArr[]= $anchor->attr['data-key'];
   $myArr[]= $anchor->attr['data-name'];


}

print_r($myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

foreach ($html->find('a[class=IconDownload]') as $anchor){
   echo $anchor->attr['data-key'];
}
```

Comment: i am still getting a blank white screen. It worked on you ?